# Sql Query to list cuisines

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Ingredient (iID, iname, madeIn)
Dish (dID, dname, cuisine, vegetarian, introduction)
Recipe (dID, iID, usageDec)
```

List the dID, dname of the dish(s) that use all 3 ingredients (“Ginger”, “Onion” and “Garlic”) in its recipe. In descending order of dID, remove duplicates.

I have given my code below. Not getting the right output. Help me out please.

```
SELECT Distinct d.dID, D.dname
FROM Dish D, Ingredient I, Recipe R 
WHERE D.dID=R.dID AND 
I.iname="Garlic" AND
I.iname="Ginger" AND
I.iname="Onion"
ORDER BY D.dID DESC;
```

Comment: Hint: Use SQL JOIN

Comment: Could you correct my code and tell me the changes

Comment: Please povide sample data and desired result

Comment: SELECT Distinct d.dID, D.dname
FROM Dish D  
JOIN Recipe R ON D.dID=R.dID
JOIN Ingredient I ON R.iID=I.iID
WHERE I.iname="Garlic" AND I.iname="Ginger" AND I.iname="Onion"
ORDER BY D.dID DESC; Rewritten to preferred JOINs-style.But wen need some sample data to write the correct query